# Can we make an applied electric field so strong that there are too few electrons in a conductor to nullify the field to zero inside the conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

What if we keep increasing the external electric field—as electrons in a conductor are finite–so that after saturation there won't be further electrons to nullify the external electric field? In this situation, will there be any field inside the conductor?

Comment: Sure, once you don't have enough electrons to screen the field, there will be some field in the material.

Answer (score 0):

Conductivity ($\sigma$) is in units of $\frac{A}{ V}$ - in other words how much current do you generate per unit of potential difference across two points? So if you've gotten to a point where there are no free charges and no current results from changing the potential, **you no longer have a conductor**.